# FileReader is not reading 1stCharacter

Tags: java, file-io

Hello friends,
                    I am making a program in which a txt file is being read and shown for output. I am using FileReader and the editor of eclipse juno for this. But while I am doing this, I am able to read the full txt file but not the first character. For example, say we have txt file in which: 
"Freedom of Spartacus" is written, so the compiler should have to show in result the whole string. Instead of this, it is showing "reedom of Spartacus" thus not showing the first character. Here is my code:

```
package file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class O 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        File f1=new File ("tj.txt");
        FileReader f2=new FileReader(f1);
        f2.read();
        System.out.println("Starting TO Read");
        long size=f1.length();
        char[] x=new char[(int)size];
        f2.read(x);
        f2.close();
        String s1=new String(x);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code and can any one help me with this?

Comment: You might consider accepting the answer which helped you most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading the first character and ignoring it here

```
f2.read();
```

Remove this line and it will work as you want.

The length is the length in bytes, not characters. It may be the same in your case, but you should read into a byte[] and use that to build the String.

Instead I suggest

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("tj.txt");
byte[] bytes = new bytes[(int) fis.getChannel().size()];
fis.read(bytes);
fis.close();
String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // or your preferred encoding.
```

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are right that the OP might not get what I am suggesting. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

remove the first

```
f2.read();
```

line

Answer (score 2):

Because of this line:

```
f2.read();
```

You have already gone passed the `F`.  You want this code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        File f1=new File ("tj.txt");
        FileReader f2=new FileReader(f1);
        System.out.println("Starting TO Read");
        long size=f1.length();
        char[] x=new char[(int)size];
        f2.read(x);
        f2.close();
        String s1=new String(x);
        System.out.println(s1);

    }
```

Comment: the `length()` is the size in bytes, not chars

Answer (score 2):

With the first `f2.read()` you read the first character but you don't store it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading/skipping that character yourself by calling `f2.read()` on the third line in your `main()`.